# Is there any way to undo the changes of a file after it is saved

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there any way to undo the changes of an exel file after it is saved

i was workin on a file since yesterday and just before half hour i finish it

then just before 5 minute the kids by mistake remove all my work and save empty file and close it

is there any way to undo it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Windows Vista, you could try using Shadow Copies. See [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/howdoi/?p=145), and skip to the part "Using shadow copies".

You could protect yourself against this in the future by using Dropbox(.com), which automatically syncs your files and stores them online so you can use them anywhere you want. Dropbox also offers basic versioning an it has a free version.

Comment: One thing to note is that if you still have the file open in an Office product, the copy will not be pushed up to Dropbox, as the file is locked by the Office product.  I just noticed this yesterday when working on a Word file in Dropbox

Comment: thanks alot, but what about the current problem is there any way to return it?

Comment: I have to add that Shadow Copies is also available in Windows 7, Vista's successor. Are you using one of these operating systems, or did you install some sort of backup/security software in the past?

Comment: i have windows 7

the problem since a long time i didn't take backup